# Trouble With HTML Tags In Accordance With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, tags

This is my code that works perfectly but only for a single quote (reference on this later):

```
<section class="quote">
    <div class="content">
        <h4>Bruce Lee</h4>
            <p>Ever since I was a child I have had this instinctive urge for expansion and growth. To me, the function and duty of a quality human being is the sincere and honest development of one's potential.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want though to include a random quote generator. I already have the script and the following:

```
<section class="quote">
    <div class="content">
        <p><script language="JavaScript">
            /* Copyright 2004 by CodeLifter.com */ 
            var Quotation=new Array()

            Quotation[0] = "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.";
            Quotation[1] = "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.";
            Quotation[2] = "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.";
            Quotation[3] = "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.";
            Quotation[4] = "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.";
            Quotation[5] = "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.";
            Quotation[6] = "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.";
            Quotation[7] = "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.";
            Quotation[8] = "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.";
            Quotation[9] = "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.";

            var Q = Quotation.length;
            var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
            function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
            showQuotation();
        </script></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

The problem: I want to associate the script that produces a random quote with its author in accordance with its tags `<p>` for quote and `<h4>` for author (as referenced in my first set of code). I am then having trouble figuring out how I would do that.

How would I write the script that produces a random quote and includes the author? And how would I define them with their certain tags?

Would it be something like this:

```
Quotation[0] = "Why must we question pancakes?";
Author[0] = "Sigmund Freud";
```

But now how would I have them be associated with their certain tags:
Quotation with the `<p>` tag and author with `<h4>` tag.

The quote section, specifically.

Update:

```
 <section class="quote">
    <div class="content">
        <h4></h4>
        <p></p>

        <script language="JavaScript">
        /* Copyright 2004 by CodeLifter.com */ 
        var Quotation = [];

        Quotation[0] = ["example Author 1", "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair."];
        Quotation[1] = ["example Author 2", "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces."];
        Quotation[2] = ["example Author 3", "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon."];
        Quotation[3] = ["example Author 4", "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes."];
        Quotation[4] = ["example Author 5", "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable."];
        Quotation[5] = ["example Author 6", "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted."];
        Quotation[6] = ["example Author 7", "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside."];
        Quotation[7] = ["example Author 8", "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors."];
        Quotation[8] = ["example Author 9", "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill."];
        Quotation[9] = ["example Author 10", "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys."];

        var Q = Quotation.length;
        var whichQuotation = Math.round(Math.random() * (Q - 1));

        document.querySelector('h4').textContent = Quotation[whichQuotation][0];
        document.querySelector('p').textContent = Quotation[whichQuotation][1];
        </script>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: In the first set of code, I have a quote defined with the "p" tag and the author with the "h4" tag. I want to do the same but in association with the script. I want the random quote generator to produce a random quote associate with it's author but they have to be defined with their according tags "p" and "h4". I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Ok. You intend the second to be an attempt at how to make a the first snippet dynamic. That's not at all how you write JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. You might might it clear that your second snippet is an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `.querySelector('p')` or `.querySelector('h4')` what you're looking for?

```
document.querySelector('h4').textContent = // Author
```

Try this:

```html
<section class="quote">
  <div class="content">
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  var Quotation = [];

  Quotation[0] = ["example Author 1", "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair."];
  Quotation[1] = ["example Author 2", "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces."];
  Quotation[2] = ["example Author 3", "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon."];
  Quotation[3] = ["example Author 4", "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes."];
  Quotation[4] = ["example Author 5", "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable."];
  Quotation[5] = ["example Author 6", "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted."];
  Quotation[6] = ["example Author 7", "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside."];
  Quotation[7] = ["example Author 8", "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors."];
  Quotation[8] = ["example Author 9", "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill."];
  Quotation[9] = ["example Author 10", "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys."];

  var Q = Quotation.length;
  var whichQuotation = Math.round(Math.random() * (Q - 1));

  document.querySelector('.content > h4').textContent = Quotation[whichQuotation][0];

  document.querySelector('.content > p').textContent = Quotation[whichQuotation][1];
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not know much on Query or JS thus I am unsure how that would written out. Though I do not want the random quote to be randomly generated by the user 'clicking something' only by refreshing the page.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have more than one `<p>` or `<h4>`, then what you need to do is assign a class or id to that so you can better reference it in JavaScript.

Comment: Updated the example to show you how you would link your author to the quote. Try the snippet out.

Comment: Tim, thank you. It seems to be working on my editor but I can't seem to get the quotation output. I updated the post with your suggestion. It's after the "Update:" part. Cheers.

Comment: Try removing `language="JavaScript"` and also update the `.querySelector` argument to what I have. See if that works.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it works!

Comment: It works but only if you change the value of "p" on the index.html and style.css within the quote section to another thing such as "x". Nonetheless, thank you. I also read your website. It looks sweet. Have you thought about attending App Academy or other bootcamps or are going to school? I am in my second year in community college but thinking about leaving to attend AA. I am actually studying for the second coding challenge. Cheers!

Comment: Don't forego an actual college education for a coding bootcamp. Unless you're a guru in programming, prospective employers will still expect a college degree in addition to the programming skill that you will need. For myself, I already have bachelors degrees in Biology/Psychology, which puts me in a different position. Nonetheless, I would recommend [Free Code Camp](https://freecodecamp.com) for learning full stack JavaScript. The start may be rough, and many recommend starting with CodeAcademy first. Cheers

Comment: I disagree with the first part. I know it's a risk but I have been thinking and planning of attending for the last four months. And the thought of leaving school does make me feel unsteady. I do love school but I believe this the right thing to do, personally. I have emailed the founder a month ago explaining my situation and he noted, in present day you don't need a degree to code. Here is a article about it: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/want-to-code-a-university-degree-might-be-a-huge-waste-of-time-81e1817a2ef0#.p3u222sec. Thank you for the link, by the way.

Comment: I get what you're saying. If that's the case, you have to make up for the time outside of university with actual projects because it's likely you'll be competing against others who have degrees in addition to projects/capstone projects from their university. At the end of the day, if both applicants have demonstrated projects of equal value in the eyes of the prospective employer, I'm inclined to believe they would pick the person with the degree. Of course, how much weight a degree holds depends on the prospective employer. Maybe times are changing.

Comment: I think skills, projects, etc trump a university degree. And you're right, maybe a degree gives you bonus points but I don't think by a large margin. The point of bootcamps such as http://www.appacademy.io/ is to teach you those skills while making you build projects every week. Learning and building Mon. thru Sat. from 9 to 6 for 3 mo. You can learn almost everything online these days (check this out, you might find it of use: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BD8BJJUNaX63m2QmySWMGDp71nx4W4MyyiIBlfMoN3Q/htmlview?sle=true#) thus more and more companies are not requiring degrees.

Comment: Perhaps the legitmacy of having graduated from a bootcamp is enough for employers then. Otherwise there's the option of going full-time self-pace project building with curricula such as [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com) which teaches Ruby/RoR or [Free Code Camp](https://freecodecamp.com) which teaches full stack Javascript. If there's no perceived disadvantage for employers, or you can do self pace, then this is always a tuition-free option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to store and access your quotes like this:

```
var Quotation = [
    {"author": "Sigmund Freud",   "quote": "Why must we question pancakes?"},
    {"author": "Albert Einstein", "quote": "Why are pi squared?"}
]
var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]["author"] + ' said ' + Quotation[whichQuotation]["quote"]);
```

Based on your comments I made some assumptions and took some liberties about how the interface might work.  Here's my suggested HTML:

```
<section class="quote">
    <div class="content">
        <h4>Sigmund Freud</h4>
            <p id="Sigmund Freud">Sigmund Freud quote</p>
        <h4>Albert Einstein</h4>
            <p id="Albert Einstein">Albert Einstein quote</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="New Quote" onClick="return quotation();" />
</section>
```

And then the Javascript code to go along with it:

```
function quotation() {
  var Quotation = [
    {"author": "Sigmund Freud",   "quote": "Why must we question pancakes?"}, 
    {"author": "Sigmund Freud",   "quote": "You have mother issues."}, 
    {"author": "Albert Einstein", "quote": "Why are pi squared?"},
    {"author": "Albert Einstein", "quote": "Space is on the chilly side."}
  ];
  var Q = Quotation.length;
  var whichQuotation = Math.round(Math.random() * (Q - 1));
  var el = document.getElementById(Quotation[whichQuotation]["author"]);
  console.log(el);
  el.innerHTML = Quotation[whichQuotation]["quote"];
}
```

[Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/ww2f52ch/5/) in jfiddle (keep clicking the button).

Comment: Awesome but I don't want the script to print the last part out. I want them to be outputted but within in their tags. So: Sigmund Freud will be outputted but within the "h4" tag. The quote will be outputted within the "p" tag. Does that make sense? I think I making it more complicated that it actually is.